# How to clear linker error? cross-compiling stm32 on windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, cross-compiling, stm32, ld

I am trying to cross-compile a simple c/cpp file the target is an stm32f030F4P, I was successfully able to setup the CMake files, and cmake successfully build the build.ninja file for ninja.
When I execute ninja I get the following error

> PS C:\Users\varun\Desktop\Projects\stm32f030f4p\Firmware\Blinky\build>
> ninja.exe   [1/1] Linking CXX executable .elf FAILED: .elf cmd.exe /C
> "cd . && C:\DEV-TO~1\TOOLCH~1\GCC-AR~1\102020~1\bin\AR10B2~1.EXE
> -march=armv6-m -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -DSTM32F030x4 -Og -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin --specs=nano.specs -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wno-volatile -std=c++1z -g  CMakeFiles/.elf.dir/src/main.cpp.obj -o .elf   && cd ."
> c:/dev-to~1/toolch~1/gcc-ar~1/102020~1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:
> c:/dev-to~1/toolch~1/gcc-ar~1/102020~1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libg_nano.a(lib_a-exit.o):
> in function `exit': exit.c:(.text.exit+0x1e): undefined reference to` _exit' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status ninja: build
> stopped: subcommand failed. PS

Please find my CMakeLists.txt.

```
 CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.20)
    
    INCLUDE("CMake/arm-none-eabi.cmake")
    
    SET(CMAKE_C_STANDARD    11)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD  17)
    
    PROJECT(BLINKY VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "Blinky Example")
    
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE
        LDSCRIPTS
        "ldscripts/*.ld"
    )
    
    FOREACH(file ${LDSCRIPTS})
        SET(CMAKE_CAMKE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CAMKE_LINKER_FLAGS} -T \"${file}\" ")
    ENDFOREACH()
    
    #Setup project headers
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    
    )
    
    #Setup porject sources
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE
        APPLICATION_SOURCE
        "src/*.c"
        "src/*.cpp"
    )
    
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT}.elf ${APPLICATION_SOURCE})
```

Please find my arm-none-eabi.cmake(excuse the copy paste toolchain name, had no clue what to name it)

> ```
> MESSAGE("Running : arm-none-eabi.cmake")
>
> SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR  arm)
> SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME       Generic)
>
> SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS  TRUE)
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS  TRUE)
>
> SET(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGTE_TYPE   STATIC_LIBRARY)
>
> SET(TARGET      STM32F030x4)
> SET(ARCH        armv6-m)
> SET(CPU         cortex-m0)
> SET(ARM_ISA     mthumb)
>
> SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    arm-none-eabi-gcc)
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-g++)
> SET(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-g++)
> SET(CMAKE_SIZE          arm-none-eabi-size)
> SET(CMAKE_OBJDUMP       arm-none-eabi-objdump)
> SET(CMAKE_OBJCOPY       arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
>
> SET(OPTIMISATION Og)
> SET(DEBUG "ggdb")
>
> SET(CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS  "-march=${ARCH} -mcpu=${CPU} -${ARM_ISA} -D${TARGET} -${OPTIMISATION} -${DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin --specs=nano.specs")
> SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} ")
> SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS       "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} -std=gnull")
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wno-volatile -std=c++1z")
> SET(CAMKE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} -nostartfiles -Wl, -Map, \"${TARGET}.map\" --specs-nano.specs")
> ```

My linker script is a copy paste from STM32CubeIDE

```
> /* Entry Point */ ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
> 
> /* Highest address of the user mode stack */
> _estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);  /* end of "RAM" Ram type memory */
> 
> _Min_Heap_Size = 0x200 ;  /* required amount of heap  */
> _Min_Stack_Size = 0x400 ; /* required amount of stack */
> 
> /* Memories definition */ MEMORY {   RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN =
> 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 4K   FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,  
> LENGTH = 16K }
> 
> /* Sections */ SECTIONS {   /* The startup code into "FLASH" Rom type
> memory */   .isr_vector :   {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
>     . = ALIGN(4);   } >FLASH
> 
>   /* The program code and other data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */  
> .text :   {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
>     *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
>     *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
>     *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
>     *(.eh_frame)
> 
>     KEEP (*(.init))
>     KEEP (*(.fini))
> 
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */   } >FLASH
> 
>   /* Constant data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */   .rodata :   {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
>     *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
>     . = ALIGN(4);   } >FLASH
> 
>   .ARM.extab   : {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
>     . = ALIGN(4);   } >FLASH
> 
>   .ARM : {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     __exidx_start = .;
>     *(.ARM.exidx*)
>     __exidx_end = .;
>     . = ALIGN(4);   } >FLASH
> 
>   .preinit_array     :   {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
>     KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
>     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
>     . = ALIGN(4);   } >FLASH
> 
>   .init_array :   {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
>     KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
>     KEEP (*(.init_array*))
>     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
>     . = ALIGN(4);   } >FLASH
> 
>   .fini_array :   {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
>     KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
>     KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
>     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
>     . = ALIGN(4);   } >FLASH
> 
>   /* Used by the startup to initialize data */   _sidata =
> LOADADDR(.data);
> 
>   /* Initialized data sections into "RAM" Ram type memory */   .data :
> {
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
>     *(.data)           /* .data sections */
>     *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
>     *(.RamFunc)        /* .RamFunc sections */
>     *(.RamFunc*)       /* .RamFunc* sections */
> 
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
> 
>   } >RAM AT> FLASH
> 
>   /* Uninitialized data section into "RAM" Ram type memory */   . =
> ALIGN(4);   .bss :   {
>     /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
>     _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
>     __bss_start__ = _sbss;
>     *(.bss)
>     *(.bss*)
>     *(COMMON)
> 
>     . = ALIGN(4);
>     _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
>     __bss_end__ = _ebss;   } >RAM
> 
>   /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough "RAM"
> Ram  type memory left */   ._user_heap_stack :   {
>     . = ALIGN(8);
>     PROVIDE ( end = . );
>     PROVIDE ( _end = . );
>     . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
>     . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
>     . = ALIGN(8);   } >RAM
> 
>   /* Remove information from the compiler libraries */   /DISCARD/ :  
> {
>     libc.a ( * )
>     libm.a ( * )
>     libgcc.a ( * )   }
> 
>   .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) } }
```

And finally c file is simple

> ```
> unsigned int counter;
> int main(void)
> {
>     for(;;)
>     {
>         counter++;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: `CMAKE_CAMKE_LINKER_FLAGS` and `CAMKE_LINKER_FLAGS` are a wrong names for CMake variable denoted linker flags. Correct: `CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for notifying, that's an embarassing typo.